# Google Sheets; arrayformular(if x=1 write 1 BUT if x=2 write 2)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I've got this working:
=IF(AND(B3 = "Hverdag");"Hverdag";IF(AND(B3 = "Weekend");"Weekend";""))

What I want is:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(B3:B = "Hverdag");"Hverdag";IF(AND(B3:B = "Weekend");"Weekend";"")))

Did I miss something or is there a better way doing this math?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the AND functions are needed since there is only one condition being tested.

Does this amended version work as you want:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B3:B = "Hverdag";"Hverdag";IF(B3:B = "Weekend";"Weekend";"")))`

Comment: This is excactly what I wanted. Thank you.